# Tokio UDP server

Tags: rust, udp, rust-tokio

I have the following example of a Rust Tokio UDP Echo Server. Unfortunately, I can't get it to turn off the echo to the clients. I just want to receive messages but not send anything to the clients back. How do I have to adapt the following source code? Thanks for your help.

```
#![warn(rust_2018_idioms)]

use std::error::Error;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::{env, io};
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;

struct Server {
    socket: UdpSocket,
    buf: Vec<u8>,
    to_send: Option<(usize, SocketAddr)>,
}

impl Server {
    async fn run(self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let Server {
            socket,
            mut buf,
            mut to_send,
        } = self;

        loop {
            // First we check to see if there's a message we need to echo back.
            // If so then we try to send it back to the original source, waiting
            // until it's writable and we're able to do so.
            if let Some((size, peer)) = to_send {
                let amt = socket.send_to(&buf[..size], &peer).await?;

                println!("Echoed {}/{} bytes to {}", amt, size, peer);
            }

            // If we're here then `to_send` is `None`, so we take a look for the
            // next message we're going to echo back.
            to_send = Some(socket.recv_from(&mut buf).await?);
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let addr = env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| "127.0.0.1:8080".to_string());

    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&addr).await?;
    println!("Listening on: {}", socket.local_addr()?);

    let server = Server {
        socket,
        buf: vec![0; 1024],
        to_send: None,
    };

    // This starts the server task.
    server.run().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Sourcecode from: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/examples/echo-udp.rs

Answer (score 0):

All the actual message handling is done in the `loop` of the Servers `run` function so I will only focus on that part to make the answer shorter.

### Short answer:

```
loop {
    if let Some((size, peer)) = to_send {
        println!("Received {} from {}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf[..size]), peer);
    }
    
    to_send = Some(socket.recv_from(&mut buf).await?);
 }
```

---

### Long answer:

It's important to understand how Rust async works. I would highly recommend you looking trough the Rust Async book here: https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/

The variable `to_send` is initialized with the Option value `None` in the main function (since it it is stored in the Server struct this is done what that is instantiated).

So the first time the loop runs the `if let Some(...) = to_send` will not execute since `to_send` is not `Some`. So it jumps straight to the `recv_from` line.

Basically all that happens here is using `await` the program waits for `recv_from` to return a tuple which contains the amount of bytes received and the peer from which that message came, that tuple is wrapped in a `Some` value (if you don't know how that works look up how Rust Enums and Rust Options work). `recv_from` will return that information when it receives a message and will also write the bytes of the massage into the array that was specified by the parameter. `&mut buf` is a mutable reference to `buf` that is given to `recv_from` to write into that array.

So when the end of the loop is reached and it starts again, `to_send` will now have a `Some` value containing the tuple of with the amount of bytes and the peer. In the original code this is now sent to the client via `send_to` however you can also convert that message to a uf8 string using `std::str::from_utf8(...)` and giving it the byte array. To let the function know how long that array actually is, a so called splice is created which only represents a portion of the array that has the length of the received bytes.

The resulting string can then just be printed to the console and the the next message can be received.